# Back Button on UITableViewController compiling error

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Ok so I made a back button via a tutorial, and found that it would not compile. This is in a UITableViewController, name NewTableViewContoller(class) and it gives me this error
I dont have a 10 reputation so here is the link. (sorry I'm new)

Update: I have fixed the compiling error and now wish to have my back button show me to my SearchForViewController.

[image]

Comment: The `selector` is should be like `#selector(NewTableViewContoller.back(sender:))`.

Comment: Thanks  Nirav D that worked

Comment: Welcome mate :)

Comment: Nirav D how can show my view controller when the button is pressed? Right now it shows just the back button and when pressed it does nothing. thanks

Comment: Can you show how you are moving to this `NewTableViewContoller`?

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/o0JlV Nirav D, this is the mainstoryboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NewTableViewContoller` is also embed with `UINavigationController`, so you can pop from it like this way:

```
_ = navigationController?.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

If you making segue with show then you need to `dismiss` the controller instead of `popViewController`.

```
self.dismiss(animated: true)
```

Comment: @user7424546 Welcome mate :)

Comment: hmm it looks like its still not showing my view controller view, umm is that because I have two view controllers on the main.storyboard, hooked to one view controller? It might be best to send the back button to go to my secondviewcontroller. Nirav D sorry to ask so much

Comment: @user7424546 I don't get your above comment, will you please explain briefly.

Comment: when I press the back button, it still does not do anything. I would like the back button to show my secondviewcontroller, thanks, sorry for being unclear

Comment: yes there is a button on my view controller that segues by "show"

Comment: Update: it is now under SearchForViewController, I just created a cocoa touch class view controller and connected it with it. I also have a separate view controller. In my storyboard I had two view controllers setup to one view controller -> view controller, now I changed that, so the button you press to go to the tableview is on the SearchForViewController

Comment: @user7424546 Check my edited answer and try to dismiss the controller.

Comment: hmm still having troubles

Comment: @user7424546 Have you tried simply `self.dismiss(animated: true)`?

Comment: yea, is there anything else that won't let it show the SearchForVC?

Comment: @user7424546 Edit your question with current flow of your application and from you are adding back button and where you want to go.